# How to get EVENT name from event signature hash?

Tags: events, keccak, explorers

I fount that some developers can get event_signature_hash for a event's name *MyEvent(uint256)* by using bellow code:

`event_signature_hash = w3.sha3(text='MyEvent(uint256)').hex()`

But vice versa, I couldn't find anyways to detect Event's name from event_signature_hash.

Can someone give a sample to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> But vice versa, I couldn't find anyways to detect Event's name from event_signature_hash.

This is not possible, (good) hashing algorithms are intentionally one way. You cannot go from the hash to the original input.

The only way to get the name would be to have the code of the contract it originates from (or a list of the event names in it, at the very least).

Comment: Thanks! I mean, in some ways, are there some database for searching Event's name with hash?

Comment: I don't know of a topic list, although a somewhat large [function sig](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trailofbits/ethersplay/master/ethersplay/known_hashes.py) list exists. You could possibly scrape various contracts from github to build your own database.